# Local Instance Reference

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

In javascript say I have:

```
var Person = (function () {

    function Person(data) {
        data = $.extend({
            name: "",
            age: 0
        }, data);

        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }

    return Person;
})();

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
};
```

...if I understand the 'this' keyword correctly in javascript, it can refer to pretty much anything from the window object to itself to anything in-between (e.g. callers of the object).  My question is how the heck do I write methods like .getName() so that I know I'll always have a reference to the value stored in the person object's name property if I never can be sure what 'this' will refer to in that method?  Say that .getName() is called and 'this' references the window object - how the do I get the value I need then?

I'm asking because I've inherited some code using pretty heavy prototyping and I'm running into all kinds of issues trying to reference properties and methods on objects from within themselves.  Seems like I'm  missing something but I've been looking into scope, closures, and other patterns all day and I can't get around this.

Comment: You can use call and apply to bind 'this' to the instance, and  underscore/lodash uses a helper called _.bind to bind a function to an object. I try to program defensively to avoid using 'this' if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` is set by the language according to how a function/method is called.

If you have an object with a method and you do:

```
obj.method()
```

Then, `this` will be set to point to the object inside of the `method()` function.

But, if you just get that method by itself like this:

```
var p = obj.method;
p();
```

Then, because there is no object reference in the actual function call, `this` will be set to either `window` or `undefined` depending upon whether you are in strict mode or not.

Additionally, the caller can specify exactly what they want `this` to be set to using `obj.method.call()` or `obj.method.apply()` or even `p.call()` or `p.apply()` from the previous example.  You can look these methods up on MDN to see more details about how they work.

So, in your previous code, this should work:

```
function Person(data) {
    data = $.extend({
        name: "",
        age: 0
    }, data);

    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
};

var p = new Person({name:"John"});
var n = p.getName();   // will return "John"
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/a7MkP/

---

If you needed to pass `getName()` to a third party library that won't call it with the object context, then there are a few options like this:

Anonymous function:

```
var myPerson = new Person("John");
callThirdParty(function() {
    // callback that calls getName with the right object context
    return myPerson.getName();
});
```

Using `.bind()` (not suported in some older browsers):

```
var myPerson = new Person("John");
var boundFn = myPerson.getName.bind(myPerson);
callThirdParty(boundFn);
```

From your own method:

```
var self = this;
callThirdParty(function() {
    // callback that calls getName with the right object context
    return self.getName();
});
```

---

FYI, there really is no reason for the self-executing function you have surrounding your `Person` constructor function.  It just makes the code more complicated and adds no value in this case.

Comment: So in short if I can't control how .getName() is being called (say from a third party library or plugin) them I'm SOL on being able to reference any local properties on the object?

Comment: Also - thanks for the FYI on the self-executing fn - can you add a short explanation why it's not needed?  I inherited this code and want to make sure if I remove all of the ()'s I know what I'm doing.  Thanks.

Comment: @CK1 - The purpose of a self-executing function like that is to create anew function scope that could have its own local variables, local functions, etc... that are out of the global scope.  But, you aren't using any of those capabilities so there is no reason to have it.  You can use the structure I've shown in my answer for simpler code without it.

Comment: @CK1 - yes, the caller determines how `this` is set.  If you want to pass it to a 3rd party library, there are several options that I've added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are understanding the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) correctly.

> how the heck do I write methods like .getName() so that I know I'll always have a reference to the value stored in the person object's name property

You can only do so by not using `this`, and in not using prototyping. Give each object a unique function that always refers to the original object:

```
function Person(data) {
    data = $.extend({
        name: "",
        age: 0
    }, data);

    this.name = data.name;
    this.age = data.age;

    var that = this; // a reference variable always pointing to this instance
    this.getName = function() {
        // using the variable from the constructor closure
        return that.name; // a quite useless getter
    };
}

var john = new Person({name:"John"}),
    getter = john.getName;
getter(); // "John"
```

> I'm running into all kinds of issues trying to reference properties and methods on objects from within themselves

So with the above you can solve it by making all methods instance-specific. However, that undoes all the advantages of prototyping, and **should not be used**.

Instead, the one who calls a function (or a method) should be responsible to call it in the correct context:

```
john.getName();
```

If you really have to pass a function to someone which ignores that (like `addEventListener`), you can use magic stuff like [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or just apply the above pattern:

```
// from
addEventListener("click", john.sayHello); // will call the function in context of the DOM
// to
addEventListener("click", function() {
    john.sayHello(); // correct thisValue
});
```

Comment: Because what you're advising is way, way more complicated and restrictive than is required for a simple object that can be reused with multiple instances.  Objects don't need to store their own instance reference.  You don't need to make unique functions for every method.  In addition, the OP needs to understand how `this` gets set rather than try to bypass how it works.

Comment: @jfriend00: Of course I did not want to advertise this method, as noted (and now highlighted) in the lower part of the answer. However, the OP struggled to call the methods correctly (and he knows that) so he asked what do to against. I think my recommendations (last sentence) are still valid.

Comment: So I couldn't do something like cache var that = this and then do this.prototype.getName = function() { return that.name; }?

Comment: @CK1: Yes, you can't do that because the `that` variable is local-scoped to the constructor function.